# Responsive Equal Height Divs with lazyload

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have found this great solution for responsive equal height divs in rows, but it doesn't work with lazyload.

When the next set of divs is loaded, they are stacked over - no height is set.
Any idea how to add functionality for lazyload?

https://codepen.io/micahgodbolt/pen/FgqLc
Here is the code:

```
<section class="main">
  <article>text....</article>
  <article>text....</article>
//.......more blocks
</section>
```

the js:

```
equalheight = function(container){

var currentTallest = 0,
     currentRowStart = 0,
     rowDivs = new Array(),
     $el,
     topPosition = 0;
 $(container).each(function() {

   $el = $(this);
   $($el).height('auto')
   topPostion = $el.position().top;

   if (currentRowStart != topPostion) {
     for (currentDiv = 0 ; currentDiv < rowDivs.length ; currentDiv++) {
       rowDivs[currentDiv].height(currentTallest);
     }
     rowDivs.length = 0; // empty the array
     currentRowStart = topPostion;
     currentTallest = $el.height();
     rowDivs.push($el);
   } else {
     rowDivs.push($el);
     currentTallest = (currentTallest < $el.height()) ? ($el.height()) : (currentTallest);
  }
   for (currentDiv = 0 ; currentDiv < rowDivs.length ; currentDiv++) {
     rowDivs[currentDiv].height(currentTallest);
   }
 });
}

$(window).load(function() {
  equalheight('.main article');
});


$(window).resize(function(){
  equalheight('.main article');
});
```

the css:

```
article {
  float: left;
  width: 23%;
  background: #ccc;
  margin: 10px 1%;
  padding: 1%;
}

@media all and (max-width: 900px) {
article {
    width: 48%
  }
```

Please advice, if you know a better solution too.

Comment: add some snippet, code.

Comment: OMG, I forgot to paste the link! Thank you for mention it.The code is added now.